# Threejs, Keydown should move my player a certain distance but the distance increases

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Threejs project, in which I use keydown as controls for my player character in my animate function: 'a' and 'd' for left and right, 'w' and 's' for up and down.

When I keep one of the keys pressed, the distance, that my character moves will be increased over the duration of me holding the key down. 
After I release the key and press it again, my character now keeps jumping the increased distance and at some point it jumps over the whole screen with one button press.

Here is a code snippet:

```
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 87) {
            player.position.y += 0.05;


        }
        if (e.keyCode == 83) {
            player.position.y -= 0.05;


        }
        if (e.keyCode == 65) {
            player.position.x -= 0.05;


        }
        if (e.keyCode == 68) {
            player.position.x += 0.05;


        }
   });
```

Would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Unable to reproduce a problem with the posted code, but do make sure the code is executed **only once**. If executed multiple times, multiple keydown handlers would be called for each key press with result the position would change more than expected.

Comment: Is that code you posted inside of your render loop? If so, each time your render loop fires it will add **another** listener resulting in what is explained in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is better to move the logic in the render loop like this

Outside render loop:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        movementY = +0.05;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        movementY = 0.05;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        movementX = -0.05;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 68) {
        movementX = 0.05;
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = 0;
});
```

Inside render loop:

```
player.position.x+=movementX;
player.position.Y+=movementY;
```